# Orienting birefringent crystal the right way in an interferometer

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, visible-light, interferometry, birefringence

I'm working in a lab that involves transforming the polarization state of one beam of light in an interferometer via a Barium Borate (BBO) birefringent crystal. As the polarization state is altered and interfered with the other beam (whose polarization state has not been transformed), we get data that, according to our predictions should and DOES indeed look like this:

[image]

This was the only good data run I had. Most of the time my data looks like this:

[image]

This is completely wrong (look at orange data).

The initial polarization of the light before passing through the BBO crystal is linear +45, so its polarization structure has both x and y components. I put the crystal in the interferometer with the optical axis horizontal w.r.t. the ground (in the x-direction of the polarized light). Some people call this the fast axis, meaning x-component of light will pass faster than y. Why in the world would I get the first data set one day, and then the second one the next day? I haven't changed a darn thing in my interferometer. The crystal in both data sets in oriented like this:

[image]

The crystal is rotated like a coin spinning on a table. So, the optical axis never changes its orientation in the xy plane, but it does spin back into the z direction. How do I get two completely sets of data when the crystal is oriented the exact same way? (The lase beam goes through gray aperture as if it were going into your screen).

Comment: I would love to answer this question, but I’m afraid it’s impossible for me (or probably anyone on this platform) to know what changed about your setup. You say nothing changed, so I have to take you at your word. My only advice is: Assume nothing, question everything. Start messing with stuff, pay close attention to what happens, and use that to build a deep intuition of your experiment. Good luck!